# If id doesn't match path='/admin/edit/:id' then it should go to NOTFOUND page in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass those ids in **path='/admin/edit/:id'** exact component ={Edit} that are registered in table. But when I pass any other value, it goes back to Edit Component. I only want to go to edit page if those ids match the ids in table. If those dont match then it should go to **NOTFOUND page without changing the url**

For example:

```
array = [ { id=1,name='ash' }, { id=2,name='ash' } ]
```

if **array.id** matches path='/admin/edit/:**id**' then it should go their pages but if it doesn't then it should go to NotFound page without changing the url. The url should not change.

Someone please help

**Admin.jsx**

```
const history = useHistory();

const[students,setStudents] = React.useState(()=> JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('students')) || [])

const editStudent = (event)=>{

  let found = students.map(student=>student.id).includes(Number(event.currentTarget.id))

  if(found){

    history.push(`/admin/edit/${Number(event.currentTarget.id)}`)
  }
}
```

App.jsx

function App() {

return (

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Switch>
    <Route path ="/" exact component={SignIn}/>
      <Route path='/admin/edit/:id' exact component = {Edit}/>
      <Route path = '/admin/add' exact component = {Add} />
      <Route path = "/register" exact component = {Register} />
      <Route path ="/admin" exact component={Admin}/>          
      <Route component={NotFound} />
      
    </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
);
```

}
Edit.jsx

const [students,setStudents] = React.useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('students')) || [])

```
const { id } = useParams();


let unique_student_array = students.filter(student=>student.id == id)
let found_id = students.map(student=>student.id).includes(Number(id));
if(!found_id){
    // I want to redirect to **NOTFOUND PAGE**
}
```

Comment: this you need to do inside the component... something like `if (id == invalid) return <NotFoundComponent />`

Comment: In which component? Can you please show how to do it? I can send you whole file  i'm wtuck in this for 2 days

Comment: `Edit` component, since thats the one you want to keep the url even if it's not found

Comment: Do you mean in return statement of edit component? Where we render? I've tried that but it shows error of too much rendering

Comment: I will give my "loading" component example: before the return of the actual component, if there's no data, it returns the loading component.

Comment: I can't understand Can you show a piece of code or any material from where i can look upto?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function MyComponent({something}){
  if (something) return <NotFoundComponent />

  return <ActualComponent />
}
```

something like this will render "notfound" if `something`

else, it will render as normal